# How to group array to subarray by name

Tags: php, arrays

I have an format array

```
array
(
     0 => array ( id = 1, name = chimpanzee, address = Singapore )
     1 => array ( id = 2, name = meeting, address = USA  )
     2 => array ( id = 3, name = dynasty, address = Singapore  )
     3 => array ( id = 4, name = chocolate, address = Netherland  )
     4 => array ( id = 5, name = bananas, address = Singapore  )
     5 => array ( id = 6, name = fantasy, address = USA  )
     6 => array ( id = 7, name = football, address = England)
)
```

And I would like to group it into a new array based on the address field in each subarray.

```
array
(
    Singapore => array
    (
         0 => array ( id = 1, name = chimpanzee, address = Singapore )
         2 => array ( id = 3, name = dynasty, address = Singapore  )
         4 => array ( id = 5, name = bananas, address = Singapore  )
    )

    USA => array
    (
         1 => array ( id = 2, name = meeting, address = USA  )
         5 => array ( id = 6, name = fantasy, address = USA  )
    )

    Netherland => array
    (
         3 => array ( id = 4, name = chocolate, address = Netherland  )
    )

    England => array
    (
         6 => array ( id = 7, name = football, address = England)
    )
)
```

Comment: loop through your array and try something, and come back when you really get stuck

Comment: just use some of the values and assign it as keys into a new container, a simple `foreach` will do, you can just try something

Comment: have you tried anything so far?

Answer (score 0):

As @Rizier123 said, use a loop to check all array entries and copy them to a new (sorted) array like so:

```
$source_array = array(
    array( 'id' => 1, 'name' => 'chimpanzee', 'address' = 'Singapore' ),
    array( 'id' => 2, 'name' => 'meeting', 'address' = 'USA'  ),
    array( 'id' => 3, 'name' => 'dynasty', 'address' = 'Singapore'  ),
    array( 'id' => 4, 'name' => 'chocolate', 'address' = 'Netherland'  ),
    array( 'id' => 5, 'name' => 'bananas', 'address' = 'Singapore'  ),
    array( 'id' => 6, 'name' => 'fantasy', 'address' = 'USA'  ),
    array( 'id' => 7, 'name' => 'football', 'address' = 'England'),
);

$sorted_array = array();

foreach ( $source_array as $idx => $entry ) {
    // Check if country already has a array
    if ( ! isset( $sorted_array[ $entry['address'] ] ) ) {
        $sorted_array[ $entry['address'] ] = array();
    }

    $sorted_array[ $entry['address'] ][ $idx ] = $entry;
}
```

Comment: `isset()` check is not even necessary. A simple assignment within the `foreach` [will do](https://eval.in/524361).

Comment: It's there to avoid resetting the country's array if there's already an entry set (because multiple entries can be from the same `address`)

Comment: My point was that you don't have to initialize it in the first place. `$sorted_array[ $entry['address'] ][ $idx ] = $entry;` will be enough.